# Accessing a directory on an SMB share without access to the parent directory

Tags: ntfs, cifs, smb

I have an SMB share from a Windows 2019 host:

```
\\server\share
```

I can mount this using `mount.cifs` to my Linux server on `/mnt/`

I'm then trying to access a directory a few levels down:

```
\\server\share\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4 

/mnt/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
```

The Windows user account I'm using to mount the share has read permissions on `dir1`, but not on `dir2` or `dir3`. The account has Full Control over `dir4`.

On another Windows system I'm able to access `dir4` despite not having access to `dir2` or `dir3`, I have to enter the full path to access `dir4` and can't browse to it (which is fine).

On Linux I'm unable to access `dir4` even if I cd straight to it.

I'm aware this is a bit weird as on a UNIX system you need access to every parent directory in order to access a subdirectory, but I'm not sure why my example does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `noperm` in the `mount` options on your Linux-based client.

The documentation (`man mount.cifs`) states,

> `noperm` Client does not do permission checks. [...] It is typically only needed when [...] UIDs/GIDs on the client and server system do not match closely enough to allow access by the user  doing  the  mount. Note  that this does not affect the normal ACL check on the target machine done by the server software [...]

What this means is that `noperm` will switch off any attempt by the local filesystem layer to interpret the POSIX permissions synthesised by CIFS, and instead to trust that the server knows what it's doing (which it does).